# Is asking "what is the current status of _X_ on _Y_?" appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate on U&L to ask questions on the form "what is the current status of *something* on *OS version*?"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking what the current status of something is would be too localized, always, because the status changes with time. In fact I closed a btrfs question about it's stability for that very reason. However, asking about the status of a specific version of a thing on a specific os version, would not change based on time (e.g. ext4 was either in linux 2.6.28 or it wasn't ). Please be advised though that asking if something is stable enough to use is probably subjective (unless citations can be provided (e.g. ext4 on 2.6.28 was stable on disk format but perhaps not stable for production use) , and could be closed for that reason.

Comment: So am I reading you right that "current status on Mac OS X" or "current status on Debian Stable" would be too localized (in time), but "status on Mac OS X 10.4.1" or "status on Debian 6.0 with Linux 2.6.32-5" would be acceptable because they specify the "time"? Assuming of course that the question is otherwise specific enough to be answerable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  that's essentially what I'm saying yes.